# Has a walrus ever been filmed catching a seal under water?

Tags: zoology, marine-biology, diet

Walruses have been long thought to be grazing feeders, scooping up clams from the sea floor. However, when walruses bodies have been examined by scientists, frequently the remains of seals are found in their stomachs. This has led to the speculation that walruses hunt seals, however, apparently this behavior has not been observed because it would take place under water, if it occurred. The Wikipedia merely says that the "[importance of seals in the walrus diet is under debate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walrus)". Has anyone ever filmed a walrus hunting, catching and eating a seal under water?

Comment: If you can attach a camera to the head of a giant walrus, it's perhaps the best way to film it. You can send the filming suggestion to the bbc or to sir-dave's office which is well connected with nature cinamatographers. Strangely, I only found this: https://edition.cnn.com/2018/12/07/americas/seals-eels-nostril-hawaii-intl-scli/index.html